# If $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ converges to $l$, then $x_n$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\Bbb{R}$ and that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=l$$ for some $l\in(-1,1)$. How do I show that $x_n\to 0$?

For any $\epsilon>0$ we have an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ $$-\epsilon<\dfrac{x_{n+1}-lx_n}{x_n}<\epsilon$$. Now what should I use?

Comment: You know that for $n$ big enough, $|x_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1+|l|}{2}|x_n|$ and so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for some reason there is no yet an answer that you'd find useful, and despite of the danger of the downvote spree, let me elaborate on my comment. You know that $|x_{n+1}|/|x_n| \to |l| < 1$, so for $n>N$  ith $N$ big enough $|x_{n+1}|/|x_n|\leq |l| + \frac12(1-|l|) = \frac{1+|l|}2$ and hence 
$$
  |x_n|\leq \left(\frac{1+|l|}2\right)^{n-N}|x_N| \to 0
$$
for $n\to\infty$ since $\frac{1+|l|}2<1$. This is similar to the approach @5xum suggested, however here you don't have to take care of a possible mess with negative numbers.

Comment: I think your inequality is missing a term namely $x_N$

Comment: @Why: thanks, better now?

Comment: This may be a correct answer and I will not downvote it, but I think that it is a bad answer: the poster of the question will learn nothing if he will get full answers to every problem he cannot solve on his own. He asked "what should I use". This answers both "what" and "how".

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| = |l| < 1$$

is a positive answer to the ratio test for convergence of series

$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n \ .$$

And a series can only be convergent if the associated sequence is a null sequence. Therefore $x_n$ is a null sequence.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I don't think your answer is very useful because the OP probably does not yet know about convergence tests for series, but your answer is not *wrong* so I don't think you should get a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let's assume $l>0$. Then, for large values of $N$, you can assume that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < \frac{l+1}{2}$.

Comment: This implies that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < \frac{l+1}{2} < 1$ and $x_n$ is decreasing. How do we conlcude that it is also bounded?

Comment: @oyster It implies more than just the fact that it is decreasing. The fact that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is smaller than a constant *smaller* than one is important. Take a look at what happens if you multiply the inequality by $x_n$, then find the same inequality for $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain to me why this answer deserves a downvote?

Comment: I don't get the downvoters, seriously. 
But even after multiplying and finding the similar inequality for $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ I don't see why this sequence converges to $0$ :(

Comment: @oyster After working on a hint for $5$ minutes, it may be common to not find an answer yet. The annoying thing about math is that there is only one way to learn it: work. I *can* give you the answer, but that will help nobody. Work on the question for a bit more before asking for aditional hints. $5$ minutes is simply not enough.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but in your case one has to take care of showing that the fraction is actually positive when the limit is - some additional work which is not needed. I do think that another answer is as useful as using Taylor expansion in a question asking why $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ for $x\to 0$, so the number of downvotes there does not really surprise me, not to say about the way the explanation was asked for. Also, I think accusing the OP of downvotes is not really the way to go, unless you saw his/her reputation changing

Comment: @Ilya I did not accuse the OP of downvoting, I only asked him if he did. That was because both answers that were posted got downvotes and none of them deserved them. It has happened very often that new users did not understand the concept of downvoting, so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Take $L$ any number between $|l|$ and $1$. Then there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ you have
$$
  \frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|} \le L
$$
hence, by a simple induction argument:
$$
  |x_{N+k}| \le L |x_{N+k-1}| \le \dots \le L^k |x_N| \to 0.
$$

Comment: how is that different from my answer?